# How to understand the expert MNIST example in tensforflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I'm reading the [Deep MNIST for Experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) and have a question here:

In this tutorial, it build first convolutional layer with code:

```
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
```

When building the second convolutional layer, the tutorial use code below:

```
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
```

and said:

> The second layer will have 64 features for each 5x5 patch.

I can't understand why the third dimension of [5, 5, 32, 64] is 32.

Does this mean the second convolutional layer do convolute with all 32 outputs of the first convolutional layer?

But when check this [3D Visualization of a Convolutional Neural Network](http://scs.ryerson.ca/~aharley/vis/conv/), each filter of the second convolutional layer just connect to some outputs of the first convolutional layer, I used to think of this as integration of several different lower features and generate some higher features, so what the difference?

Sorry for my poor expression, now I am very confused.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convolutions (at least in a context of the convolutional neural networks) are usually performed **depthwise**, meaning that each cell of new feature map is a 'dot product' between the particular kernel and the corresponding part of input feature map but with the use of all available channels.

Comment: In the last few days, I was reading ["CS231n from Stanford"](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) and now I can finally understand what you mean, thanks for your help!